# How do I remove error code 403 on locally made website running in linux xampp from windows wampp server?

Tags: php, linux, xampp

I created a web-application running on Wampp server, transferred all the files to a linux machine running Xampp but after inserting the web-app files in the htdocs folder, and starting the server I ran the web-app and ran into an error 403

"Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."

I tried connecting the machine to the internet because I had embedded bootstrap into my code.
I also imported the necessary database in phpmyadmin and this was successful but still I had no access to my web-app.

Comment: You need to adjust the fileystem permissions on the files so that the account which runs the webserver has permissions to read them (at least - maybe needs read+execute).

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. This definitely worked I just had to change permissions the files and it all worked.